# jquery : Globalize.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have problem while using Globalize.js in my web application.
This is how I declare the scripts references in _Layout.cshtml :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/globalize/globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/globalize/cultures/globalize.cultures.js"></script>
```

and this is how I implement it in the page (Create.cshtml) :

```
Globalize.culture("en-US");
var NomDia = Globalize.parseFloat(0.005);
```

Somehow an error being returnd as below :

```
TypeError: value.indexOf is not a function
```

And the error is occur in Globalize.js script.
May I know what I have done wrong and cannot make it able to functioning properly ?

Kindly advise

Comment: I'm gonna guess that `value` is not a string which will cause this problem.

Comment: If you are passing a float, you don't need to .parse(), but if you get a form from a webpage it would be a string and you would do a Globalize.parseFloat("0,2")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing `parseFloat` is meant to take a string rather than a float. That would explain why you're getting `value.indexOf` is not a function (Strings have that method whereas numbers don't):

```
var nomDia = Globalize.parseFloat('0.005');
```

Although, I just double checked the Globalize documentation and noticed that there is no `parseFloat` so I'm guessing you're using `parseNumber` instead:

```
var nomDia = Globalize.parseNumber('0.005');
```

Comment: ^ has it.  Refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Comment: @Deryck - The OP isn't calling the built-in `parseFloat` method. He's calling https://github.com/jquery/globalize/blob/master/doc/api/number/parse.md

Comment: @Deryck,@Justin Niessner - yes, it is because not a string, now it is OK. And actually I am using "parseFloat" because if "parseNumber, it will return an error "TypeError: Globalize.parseNumber is not a function". Thanks all

Comment: probably original post was done with Globalize.js 0.1.x, and and I am sure that jQuery validation, in case of error, replaces "value" with false, then in boolean .indexOf is unavailable

Answer (score 0):

For Globalize.js v. 0.13 i solved with

```
  $.validator.methods.number = function (value, element) {
        if (value != false) {
            if (Globalize.parseFloat(value)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```